# Manually terminating iterative/convergent loop?

Tags: python, signals, keyboardinterrupt

I do a lot of data analysis in Python. There are a lot of algorithms out there that are set up in such a way that they gradually approximate a good output to a question, and break when a maximum number of iterations or a tolerance parameter is reached. (*pseudocode*)

```
def fn(X):
    answer = initial_guess(X)
    for i in range(max_iterations):
       answer = refine_answer(X, answer)
       if is_good_enough(answer):
          break
    return answer
```

If I have a lot of time on my hands, I just wait until the function is done. But for interactive analysis, this can be quite annoying and suboptimal because most of the improvement comes on the first few iterations with diminishing returns from there. We are talking about 15 minutes+ algorithms here for total convergence.

So what I am looking for is a good way to be able to, optionally, manually interrupt such a loop prematurely without borking my interpreter and then returning the current best result so that I can continue with my analysis.

I think I may be able to do this by catching a `KeyboardInterrupt`, or maybe more vaguely, by catching some other signal so that I can still use Ctrl+C if that is what I actually want. Is there a standard or good way to do this?

Comment: Check if the optimizer you're using takes parameters to control this. I know `scipy.optimize.minimize` does.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they almost always do. Usually there are `max_iterations` and `tolerance` parameters. But that only works ahead of time, not manually. For the purposes of this question, I'm talking about functions that I write, because it would be difficult and impractical to modify third-party functions in such a way.

Comment: I think I would do this by catching `KeyboardInterrupt` and planning to hit control-C twice if I really wanted to interrupt the whole thing after aborting the loop. But I wouldn't be shocked if there's a better way.

Comment: You could have your break condition on the compute time instead of the precision of the answer